# Python- Generic/Inbuilt function to Decode a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to decode a string

`abc,1236,hg898,111112222,XXXX`

The format is as follow

`Format: pincode ,sid, xyz,DSP,4-Character code.`

Other sample can be like this

`abc1236hg898111112222XXXX`

`

```
Format: 
     pincode=first 3 letters , 
     sid = first next 4 letters,
     xyz = next 5 letters,
     DSP = next 9 letters,
     4-Character code = last 4 letters.
```

ie `pincode = %3s sid = %4s xyz = %5s DSP = %9s 4-Charchode = %4s`
`

So basically I want to have a generic function that can decode the string for me provided the format.

So, the function should be

```
def string_decoder(string,format):
    #return the dict having keys as format keys and values as their respective values
```

**How do I do it?**

Is there something inbuilt function as such in Python?

Comment: Comma may be there in the string?

Comment: May/May not be. As I provided in my 2nd sample It can be without comma as well, and can be like 1st 4 letters, next 3 letters.

Comment: You've illustrated the problem, but [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I think the term is you want to _unpack_ a string, since the values are right there for all to see.

Comment: do you have a description of the format you would like to use? it's pretty easy to write an algorithm to process a string for a given format, but you'd need to define it first. do you want something scanf like? or more like unpack?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
match = re.match(r'''(.{3}),?
                     (.{4}),?
                     (.{5}),?
                     (.{9}),?
                     (.{4})''', string, flags=re.VERBOSE)
if match:
    pin, sid, xyz, dsp, fourcharcode = match.groups()
else:
    handle_error()
```

`.{3}` means 3 arbitrary characters. `,?` means an optional comma. Parentheses around `.{3}` saves the 3 arbitrary characters as a capturing group. Combined, this regex breaks the input string into groups of 3, 4, 5, 9, and 4 characters, optionally with commas between them.

If you want the number and sizes of the groups to be specified as arguments to a function, you can build the regex at runtime:

```
def break_groups(string, *sizes):
    regex = r',?'.join(r'(.{%d})' % size for size in sizes)
    match = re.match(regex, string)
    if match:
        return match.groups()
    else:
        raise SomeSortOfError
```

Comment: +1 You might want to change the second and the fourth to `\d`

Comment: @user2357112 - I tried it. It works but as I said I want it configurable, ie pin can be first 3 letters or first 10 letters and so on.

Comment: @user1162512 Now as you have a working sample, you can start working on your own solution.

Comment: I tried the other sample, which is only comma-separated values, but it doesn't match anything.`match = re.match('''(.{}),?
      (.{}),?
      (.{}),?
      (.{}),?
      (.{})''', string, flags=re.VERBOSE)`

Comment: Since the other format can be only comma-separated values, how does this matches with this use case?

Comment: @user1162512: Why did you take the numbers out? If the values are comma-separated, are you supposed to accept arbitrary field lengths instead of fixed sizes?

Comment: Yes., it can be of arbitary length if the format provided is only comma-separated values. That's why I said Is there something generic that I provide the format and string, and it gives me the decoded string?

Comment: @user1162512 Give the functionality in all cases. 1. What is the desired functionality when the string contains commas, and 2. What is the desired functionality when the string does not contain commas? It is a bit hard to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use split function on your String
 ex:

```
a="abc,1236,hg898,111112222,XXXX"
b=a.strip()
print b
b=[abc,1236,hg898,111112222,XXXX]
```

now you can get value by index

```
print b[0]
>>> abc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def string_decoder(string, format):
    ret = {}
    if len(string) == len(format):
        for item in string:
            ret[format] = string
    else:
        print 'input wrong!'
```